# How to block a site for a certain screen size?

Tags: php, javascript

My site is not available for displays smaller than 10". How can I determine the size of the screen to block access to the site at resolutions below 10"? Thanks.

Comment: Why 10 inches? What does your site do?

Comment: 10" isn't a resolution, it just the size of a screen

Comment: I think you can only detect browser window size and screen resolution

Comment: You should never ever block access to your site on conditions like that. If you want to apply your cool stylesheet only for >800px display size, there are technologies to do that.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect the user's screen size. The only thing that might be available to you (and can be easily spoofed) is the display resolution in pixels.

To apply a stylesheet only if your content has more than XYZ px room, I recommend use of [`width` media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width).

Answer (score 5):

A computer can and has to know the *resolution* (in pixel) that it is displaying. The image in this resolution is then send across a cable to another device which physically displays it. This could be a tiny LCD screen or a giant projector. Either way, the physical screen/display size is entirely independent of the screen resolution. The final physical size of the output is unknown by the computer and especially Javascript/CSS.

In other words: you cannot detect "10 inches".

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with CSS Media Queries, hide all the content of your site and display a message to blocked people.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : YOURWIDTHpx) {
/* Styles */
 YOUR MESSAGE CONTAINER
}
```

Though it would make sense to just show something useful to these people rather than block them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Create an element with its `.style.width` defined in inches, then measure it's `.width` (in pixels) to figure out the screen's DPI. Then you just need to use [the `screen` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen) to figure out the screen's diagonal size and block users however you want.

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.style.width = "100in";
document.body.appendChild(el);

var dpi = el.clientWidth / 100;
var screenSizeIn = Math.sqrt(screen.width * screen.width +
                             screen.height * screen.height) / dpi;

console.log("Screen size is " + screenSizeIn + " inches.");

document.body.removeChild(el);

if (screenSizeIn < 10) {
  window.location = "/blocked.html";
}
```

If the device doesn't know how big an inch *actually* is (and many don't), you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

For checking on resolution.

In javascript:

```
if(screen.height < 600 || screen.width < 800)
{
    // Do something to block. i.e. redirect to specific page
}
```